# dpkg: error processing package fail2ban (--configure):

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

I am trying to install fail2ban service on my ubuntu server 16.04, but i have this error and fail2ban service cannot start, what's the problem?

```
root@clm:~# apt install fail2ban
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
fail2ban is already the newest version (0.9.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up fail2ban (0.9.3-1) ...
Job for fail2ban.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status fail2ban.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript fail2ban, action "start" failed.
● fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-29 18:08:01 CET; 8ms ago
     Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 4888 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=255)

Dec 29 18:08:01 domain systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Dec 29 18:08:01 domain systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 29 18:08:01 domain systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package fail2ban (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fail2ban
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The log say it's just like this,

```
root@clm:~# systemctl status fail2ban.service
● fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-29 18:27:09 CET; 9min ago
     Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 7277 ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7301 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 7026 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Dec 29 18:27:09 domain systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Dec 29 18:27:09 domain systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Dec 29 18:27:09 domain systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 29 18:27:09 domain systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 29 18:27:09 domain systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 29 18:27:09 domain systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
Dec 29 18:27:09 domain systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 29 18:27:09 domain systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
root@clm:~# tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log 
2017-12-29 18:26:08,198 fail2ban.actions        [7026]: INFO    Set banTime = 600
2017-12-29 18:26:08,262 fail2ban.filter         [7026]: INFO    Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
2017-12-29 18:26:08,330 fail2ban.filter         [7026]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
2017-12-29 18:26:08,331 fail2ban.filter         [7026]: INFO    Set maxRetry = 5
2017-12-29 18:26:08,331 fail2ban.filter         [7026]: INFO    Set maxlines = 10
2017-12-29 18:26:08,448 fail2ban.server         [7026]: INFO    Jail sshd is not a JournalFilter instance
2017-12-29 18:26:08,465 fail2ban.jail           [7026]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
2017-12-29 18:27:05,924 fail2ban.server         [7026]: INFO    Stopping all jails
2017-12-29 18:27:06,756 fail2ban.jail           [7026]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' stopped
2017-12-29 18:27:06,831 fail2ban.server         [7026]: INFO    Exiting Fail2ban
```

Comment: What do the logs say? As written in the message: See "systemctl status fail2ban.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is the problem,

After i check with `journalctl -xe`, i found a (maybe wrong configuration / this is a bug), this the log:

```
Dec 29 18:46:27 *domain* fail2ban-client[7530]: ERROR  Failed during configuration: While reading from '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local' [line 99]: option 'port' in section 'pam-generic'
```

so i give try to give a comment on `line 99` like the log say, and it's working right now, whereas before, i try to implement on ubuntu 14.04 is working well

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there's a problem in the configuration file. try running

```
fail2ban-server  -f -x
```

and see what happens

Comment: that command it just give me `2017-12-29 18:54:56,420 fail2ban.server         [7680]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.9.3 ....`, that's right, the problem is come from configuration, thank you